# How to specify the Python version such that it is added to the wheel file name?

Tags: python, hatch

I have this in my pyproject.toml file:

```ini
requires-python = ">=3.8.1,<3.9"
```

I know this does not specify what Python version is added to the wheel file name, but I cannot figure out how to do it using [hatch build](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/build/).